# Using pumping lemma to prove that $L=\{ab^nab^k \mid n>k>3\}$ is not regular

Tags: automata, regular-language

I want to use **pumping lemma** to prove that $L=\{ab^nab^k \mid n>k>3\}$  is not regular.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#General_version_of_pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)  of the pumping lemma.

Assume that the given language is regular. Let $p$ be a pumping length ( $p$ can be the number of states of an automaton that recognizes the language). Consider the word of the language
$$a b^{q} a b^r$$
with $q >r > 3$ and $r\ge p$. Then there exists a subword of $b^r$ that is pumpable, of length $s$, $1\le s \le p$. Then all of the words
$$a b^r a b^{r+ (k-1) s}$$
are in the language, for all $k\ge 1$. For $k$ large enough we have $r+ (k-1) s > q$, contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a possible hint:

Suppose that $L$ is regular and let $p$ be the pumping length as in the pumping lemma. Let $\gamma = \max\{p, 4\}$ and the string $ab^{\gamma + 1}ab^{\gamma}$ is in $L$.

The pumping lemma implies that the pumpable portion of the string has to be a substring of the $ab^{\gamma + 1}$ portion. Try to derive a contradiction from here.